# Strange CRC calculation

Tags: crc

I'm going to connect to a device (MODBUS protocol), and I have to calculate CRC (CRC16). There are standard implementations of this protocol, but I have to create my CRC using this formula:

X15 + X2 + 1 (there is a standard implementation with this formula: X16 + X15 + X2 + 1)

I've tested differnt values for CRC, but none of them is giving me the correct answer. I should write some bytes to a port, and at the end of this byte string I should write two CRC bytes in order to obtain my device information.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: my question is about the correct way of finding the CRC using X15+X2+1 formula, how should I write this bytes to my port? I use C# (VS2010), should I use port.write or port.writeline? how should I pass these bytes to port? as ascii strings or as hex? thanks

Comment: You should pass the bytes as raw binary strings (which you can form from a byte array), neither ASCII strings nor hex. You can use Port.Write. You will likely need to use [Port.ByteArrayToString](http://franson.com/serialtools/reference_manual.asp?class=Port&item=ByteArrayToString&platform=net).

Answer (score 2):

What is your question?
I'm assuming your question is "How do I calculate a MODBUS CRC at the end of a message so the MODBUS device at the other end of the cable recognizes it as a valid MODBUS message?"

I try to get test vectors in hand first,
before I implement yet another checksum or CRC function.

Do you have any examples of valid messages, *including* the proper/expected CRC at the end?

According to Wikipedia: [cyclic redundancy check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check),
"Since the high-order bit is always 1, and since an n-bit CRC must be defined by an (n+1)-bit divisor which overflows an n-bit register, some writers assume that it is unnecessary to mention the divisor's high-order bit."

So writers that say that MODBUS uses a "X^15 + X^2 + 1" polynomial (with an understood x^16, since it's a 16-bit CRC) are referring to exactly the same polynomial as other writers that say MODBUS uses a "X^16+X^15+X^2+1" polynomial.
Both authors will write code that generates exactly the same CRC and are interoperable with each other.

Also, people calculating the standard MODBUS CRC in the "foward" direction often use the magic constant "0x8005".
Those calculating the standard MODBUS CRC in the "reverse" direction often use the magic constant "0xA001" instead (the bitwise-reverse of "0x8005").
Both people write code that generates exactly the same CRC bytes and are interoperable with each other.

There are many implementations online of MODBUS CRC calculation;
perhaps you might find one of them useful.

online live CRC calculator with many options
http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html

On-line CRC calculation
http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

and many others, in no particular order:

[a](http://modbus.org/specs.php) [b](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/crc/index.html) [c](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__crc.html) [d](http://www.control.com/thread/1026225391) [e](http://www.protocessor.com/solutions/Free-Modbus-RTU-Source-Code.php) [f](http://www.modbus.pl/node/23) [g](http://www.ccontrolsys.com/w/How_to_Compute_the_Modbus_RTU_Message_CRC) [h](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m410926.aspx) [i](http://cubloc.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=3356) [j](https://code.google.com/p/libext2fs-wii/source/browse/trunk/source/crc16.c) [k](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/24881-CRC-16-0xA001-polynomial) [l](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmodbus/) [m](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/)
[n](http://qmodbus.sourceforge.net/) [o](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modbusc/) [p](http://www.dsprelated.com/showcode/295.php) [q](http://www.simplymodbus.ca/)

Many implementations are byte-oriented, which run a little faster but require a big lookup table
(and it's far from obvious to me how to *test* whether the lookup table is valid).

Many implementations are bit-oriented, which produce a much shorter program size
and have fewer dusty corners where bugs can lurk (but take about 8 times as long to calculate the checksum), such as the following:

```
// warning: untested code
// optimized for size rather than speed
// (i.e., uses a bit-oriented calculation rather than table-driven calculation)
uint16_t modbusCRC(uint8_t* data, int length) {
    uint16_t crc = 0xFFFF;
    for(int pos = 0; pos<length; pos++){
        crc ^= (uint16_t)data[pos];
        for( int i=0; i<8; i++ ){
            if(crc & 1){      // LSB is set
                crc >>= 1;                 // Shift right
                crc ^= 0xA001;             // XOR 0xA001
            }else{                         // LSB is not set
                crc >>= 1;
            };
        };
    };
    return crc;
}
int main(void){
    uint8_t message[80] = { // 6-byte test vector
      0x11, 0x03, 0x00, 0x6B, 0x00, 0x03
    };
    int message_length = 6;
    uint16_t the_CRC = modbusCRC(message, message_length); // find CRC of the message
    message[message_length++] = the_CRC & 0xFF; // send low byte first
    message[message_length++] = the_CRC >> 8; // then send high byte
    assert( 0x76 == message[6] ); // test against known-good CRC
    assert( 0x87 == message[7] );
    send_message(message, message_length); // send all 8 bytes of the message,
    // including the two MODBUS CRC bytes.
    // (Must send *all* 8 bytes of the message,
    // even though there are multiple 0x00 bytes).
}
```

"Binary MODBUS" ("Modbus RTU Frame Format") sends all the data of the message as raw 8-bit bytes, including the 2 CRC bytes.

"ASCII MODBUS" ("Modbus ASCII Frame Format") sends the message as more-or-less plain ASCII text, including an 8 bit checksum.
(The checksum is transmitted as 2 bytes -- as 2 ASCII hexadecimal characters).